# Why does this Service Worker manifest changes request URL for icon images

Tags: service-worker

I have a JavaScript file with the service worker logic content request URL nested in a directory. I have the ability to and have configured the web server to serve that file with HTTP header Service-Worker-Allowed as "/".

The manifest file is also located in a directory reflecting the request URL. However, the scope and images are set assuming the same request URL is set to the main scope.

The actual request URL I see is set relative to the directory from the manifest, not the root directory I want to start from.

So this is the timeline of the browser:

First, request the website which returns the index file: `https://localhost:3000`.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <link rel="manifest" href="json/manifest.json" async>
        <script id="js-webapp" type="module" src="js/webapp.js" defer async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second, it parses that and requests the main app logic: `https://localhost:3000/js/webapp.js`.

webapp.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    const path = '/js/sw.js'
    
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        console.log('Service Worker present')
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(path, { scope: './'})
            .then((registration) => {
                console.log('Service Worker Registered', registration)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Service Worker Failed to Register: ', err)
        })
    }
})
```

Third, my app logic determines whether or not to load a service worker file based on the browser configuration: `https://localhost:3000/js/sw.js`. (This is the HTTP header that has response key-val "service-worker-allowed" and "/".

sw.js

```
const cacheName = 'v1.0.0'
const cacheFiles = [
    './manifest.json',
    './css/theme.css',
    './js/webapp.js',
    './img/logo.ico'
]
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    console.log('Installed')

event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
        console.log('Caching cacheFiles')
        return cache.addAll(cacheFiles)
        })
    )
})
```

Next, the service worker requests the manifest to cache the file: `https://localhost:3000/json/manifest.json`. (This was loaded on the main index file but nothing is done to this file without the service worker logic being triggered.)

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Web App",
    "short_name": "",
    "start_url": "/",
    "scope": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "display": "fullscreen",
    "theme_color": "#404040",
    "background_color": "#404040",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "img/ic_launcher_48.png",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Following this logic, I would expect the URL request to be `https://localhost:3000/img/ic_launcher_48.png`. However, the request URL I see being performed by the browser is `https://localhost:3000/json/img/ic_launcher_48.png`.

What am I doing wrong if I already set to the service worker allowed HTTP in the header when I served the main file that installs, activates, and fetches service worker logic?

All other content that is loaded from other JavaScript, or HTML files load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the icons `src` is relative to where the manifest file is, since your manifest is at `/json` then the browser is looking for the icon at `/json/img`

Comment: Is there a way to change that and make it relative to the main website?

Comment: Move your manifest json file to root of the directory. Ideally it should always be at root